# How do I declare a nested function in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, nested-function

How would I declare a nested function in VB.NET? For example, I want to do something like this:

```
Function one()
    Function two()
    End Function
End Function
```

However, this statement is invalid in VB.NET because of unclosed function.

Answer (score 21):

**Are you asking how to write a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)?**

> A lambda expression is a function or subroutine without a name that can be used wherever a delegate is valid. Lambda expressions can be functions or subroutines and can be single-line or multi-line. You can pass values from the current scope to a lambda expression.
>
> You create lambda expressions by using the Function or Sub keyword, just as you create a standard function or subroutine. However, lambda expressions are included in a statement.

For example, the following code will print "Hello World!":

```
Dim outputString As Action(Of String) = Sub(x As String)
                                            Console.WriteLine(x)
                                        End Sub
outputString("Hello World!")
```

For more examples, see here: [VB.NET Lambda Expression](http://dotnetperls.com/lambda-vbnet)

Comment: VB10 required for 'Sub' lambdas.

Comment: VB10 also required for multi-line function lambdas

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, this is not possible.

You have several options

- have `Function two` be a private function within the same class, so you can call it from `Function one`.
- Create a nested class or structure on the class, again private, and call methods on that.

Comment: To clarify, neither of those options allow what a *nested* function allows, which is referring to local variables by name (without having to explicitly pass them as parameters). Lambda functions are (now) the solution. For the question as asked, creating a local variable and assigning it a lambda function, as Cody shows, provides a local name for that function.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expressions were added in recent years to vb.net: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions

In Modern vb, you do the following:

```
    Function foo() as String
        Dim _bar = Function()
                       return "bar"
                   End Function

        return "foo " + _bar()
    End Function
```